# Amazon Cognito - Unable to login after reset password for imported user

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-cognito

I'm new to using Amazon Cognito on iPhone app and have been testing it using the example provided. I'm testing the import user function and having problem with it. The import was successful and reset password was required. As stated in documentation, I have to run through ForgotPassword function to change to new password. I've done this and status in my console is changed to "Confirmed". But when I try to login using the new password, I'm getting "Incorrect username or password". I'm sure my username and password is correct.

Anyone have this problem before? How can I fix this?

Comment: I have this exact same issue, did you end up solving it ? Here is a github issue referencing the same thing https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2602 more recently

Answer (score 0):

It is unexpected. Once the user is confirmed, the user should be able to login with the new password. If the problem still exists, I suggest you to check the username field. Do you use phone number or email address as the username for signing in?